# Why save in Modal Not Working ??(Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal popup where you can edit/add values.

I already created modal and show the values, when i try to edit the values and i click save to non-modal screen my values still not updated, but when i click my values inside modal is updated.

Here's sample screenshot and code below.

***My modal button and fields***
[image]

Code for my modal button

```
  <div class="inline-block pull-right mright10 projecttenancy_title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="<?php echo _l('tenancy_title'); ?>">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right" data-target="#add-edit-tenancy"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
   </div>
```

***My modal popup***
[image]

Code for modal popup

```
div class="modal fade" id="add-edit-tenancy" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <?php echo form_open(admin_url('projects/view/'.$project->id)); ?>
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo _l('Tenancy Info'); ?></h4>
         </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php echo form_hidden('project_id',$project->id); ?>
                        <div id="additional"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                   <?php $value=( isset($project) ? $project->tc_owner_name : ''); ?>
                                    <?php echo render_input( 'firstname', 'tc_owner_name',$value); ?>

                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Time -->

                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><?php echo _l('close'); ?></button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" autocomplete="off" data-loading-text="<?php echo _l('wait_text'); ?>"><?php echo _l('submit'); ?></button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-content -->
   <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

When I try to edit
and click save my values for owner name is still the same ***"Bayan"***

**Controller**

```
public function view($project_id)
{
    if (has_permission('projects', '', 'edit') || has_permission('projects', '', 'create')) {
        $this->projects_model->update($this->input->post(), $project_id);
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
```

***Model***

```
 public function update($data, $id)
{
    $_data['data'] = $data;
    $_data['id']   = $id;

    $_data = do_action('before_update_project', $_data);

    $data = $_data['data'];

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('tblprojects', $data);
}
```

But when I click my modal the edited value is showing like this
[image]

Then when I refresh the page the edited values back to normal.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Visit Here http://www.itidabhoi.org/demo/bootstrap-crud-php/

Comment: Where the update should be done?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov on my first image. I also check my table it's not updating

Comment: It is suppose to update only the `html` table or should update the `database`?

Comment: on my database table

Comment: That is you function it is suppose to update: `<?php echo render_input( 'firstname', 'tc_owner_name',$value); ?>`

Comment: If your values aren't updating it sounds like a database update issue, so why are you showing us your views instead of your model/controller?

Comment: @Alex: exactly!

Comment: I didn't put my controller/model because I also try to put this edit script outside modal and it's working.

I only facing the problem when i put it on the modal. So I'm thinking the problem is within the view not on model/controller.

Comment: then why downvote?

Comment: if there isn't enough information to answer the question then its not a complete question. we could spend hours of our time debugging a potential non-issue, but we'll never know because we don't have all the info.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question with the relevant info. So as I understand it when you change a field in the modal in click save the data is not updating? Have you tried doing a `print_r($data)` and `echo $id;` in your model function before everything to determine what kindof post data you are getting? What is the result?

Comment: Its working now. I dunno why, I just try to put all my field and then problem solve. Now I face another issue but I will make different question for that.